# Firebase notification web app

Tags: firebase, notifications, push, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to send push notifications to my web app. Is it possible to recieve notifications through firebase as it is done in Android and iOS ? Technology used: EJB, hibernate, Java . will firebase javascript sdk will work? if this does not work what else can I use. Like Facebook uses to send notification on web app

Answer (score 4):

Receiving push notifications in a web app is possible for Chrome, Firefox and Opera now with Firebase Cloud Messaging for the web. See the [FCM.js documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) for full details on how to make it work.